# Application app pool changes on SharePoint central admin change

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis, iis7

I have an sub-application living under sharepoint web application
Where my SharePoint web application is 64bit app pool and the sub application living under it is set to a different app pool of 32bit

The problem comes, when I change something through Central Admin on the web application the sub application's app pool reverts back to the parents (SP App pool 64bit mentioned above)

Let me know how to make the app pool of sub application not get changed, stay what it is.

Comment: should you tell me what the changes that you have to do through Central Admin on the web ? what's the type of sub-application ? how it live under SharePoint ?   meanwhile, you can set the Enable 32-bit application to this non-SharePoint  application to true

Comment: The problem is that app pool of the sub application gets changed if anything from central admin is updated.